# Want to fetch both id and value on select in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I am dynamically fetching category list, and based on selection again dynamically fetching Course List by ID.
I am using `formControlName` to pass the value to the database.
While fetching the course list I need the Id of the selected course category.

So, I am putting the value as `[value]="category.QuickCat_ID"`, and to display the category name I'm using `{{category.QuickCat_Name}}` within the  tag.

I am able to fetch the category Id and using it and I'm also getting Course list. However, I am getting category Id to my db (console) instead of category Name. I am writing the code below;

```html
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 clearfix" style="padding: 0px">
  <label for="courseOfInterest">Course Interested In</label>

  <div class="col-xs-12 textboxsize" style="padding:0px !important">
    <select class="form-control textboxsize" formControlName="QuickCat_Name" style="padding-top: 3px;" id="courseCat" (change)="onChange($event)">
      <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled style="color:lightgray">Select Course Category</option>              
      <option *ngFor="let category of selectCourseCat" [value]="category.QuickCat_ID" id="catId">{{category.QuickCat_Name}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-xs-12 clearfix" style="padding: 0px">
  <label for="courseName">Course Name</label>

  <select class="form-control textboxsize" formControlName="QuickCourseName"  style="padding-top: 3px;" id="courseName" (change)="getCourseName($event)">
    <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled style="color:lightgray">Select Course Name</option>
    <option *ngFor="let name of selectCourseName" [value]="name.QuickCourseName" id="coursename">{{name.QuickCourseName}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

```js
export class Studentform1Component implements OnInit {
  selectCountries: string[];  
  selectCourseCat: string[];
  selectCourseName: string[];
  value = 2;
  idValue: number;
  i: number;

  public onChange(event): void{
    const newVal = event.target.value;
    console.log(newVal);

    this.httpService.get('url?Id='+newVal).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.selectCourseName = data as string [];
        console.log(this.selectCourseName);
      },
      (err:HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

I want both `QuickCat_Name` (to send to db) and `QuickCat_ID` (to fetch course list).

Thank you :)

Comment: And if you return the object `[value]="category"` instead of just `category.QuickCat_ID`?

Comment: well, you send the event.
just console.log the event.target
inside there look for the text(I forgot which one gives you the text and not the value)

Comment: if I use [value]="category", I get value as "category" itself, not even object. And if I use [value]={{category}}, I getting "[object object]"

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow two steps to achieve that:

1. Pass the entire object to `<option>` which will be the value for select.
2. Use `compareWith` in `select` control otherwise it will not select the default value:

```html
<select class="form-control textboxsize" formControlName="QuickCourseName" 
 [compareWith]="compareFn" id="courseName" (change)="getCourseName($event)">
  <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled style="color:lightgray">Select Course Name</option>
  <option *ngFor="let name of selectCourseName" [ngValue]="name" id="coursename">{{name.QuickCourseName}}</option>
</select>
```

Don't forget to set a comparer function `[compareWith]="compareFn"`.

3. Create the comparer function in your class, comparing with the properties that you want:

```js
/* It's best to use your class/types here, instead of any */
compareFn(a: any, b: any) {
  if (!a || !b)
    return false;
  
  /* You can add your own comparisons here. */
  return a.QuickCourseName === b.QuickCourseName;
}
```

Sample example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-2z9f3b

Answer (score 0):

Pass the full category object as value like this :

```
<option *ngFor="let category of selectCourseCat" [value]="category" id="catId">{{category.QuickCat_Name}}</option>
```

This will give you entire object to your function argument.

Comment: I am getting result as [object object]. How to get values?

Comment: check your **console.log()** statement and see if you have missed the **,** and wrote a **+** sign instead

Comment: I used "console.log(newVal);" (check my .ts file above).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the array `selectCourseCat` fetch the name from the array using id

`this.selectCourseCat.filter(x => x.QuickCat_ID == newVal)[0].QuickCat_Name`

This will return you the `text` of the drop down then you can bind it if you want as an object remove `QuickCat_Name` from the above code

```
public onChange(event): void{
    const newVal = event.target.value;
    let name = this.selectCourseCat.filter(x => x.QuickCat_ID == newVal)[0].QuickCat_Name;
    this.httpService.get('url?Id='+newVal).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.selectCourseName = data as string [];
        console.log(this.selectCourseName);
      },
      (err:HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      }
      );
  }
```

Hope this helps - Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

That is what *ngValue* is for:

https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#how-to-use-select-controls-with-form-directives

*If your option values are simple strings, you can bind to the normal value property on the option. If your option values happen to be objects (and you'd like to save the selection in your form as an object), **use ngValue instead***

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can be helpful:

```js
Value = [
  {
    QuickCat_Name: 'Donald',
    QuickCat_ID: 1
  },
  {
    QuickCat_Name: 'Arnold',
    QuickCat_ID: 2
  }
]
```

You want to iterate that value in for loop to show `Cat_Name`:

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="bindValue" (change)="onChange(bindValue)">
  <option *ngFor = "let val of Value" [value]="val.QuickCat_ID">{{val.QuickCat_Name}}</option>
</select>
```

In your class, you'll be having `QuickCat_ID`. Based on that you can get both values:

```js
Value.forEach(obj => {
   if(obj['QuickCat_ID'] == 'bindValue') {
    youGotIDValue = bindValue
    youGotName = obj['QuickCat_Name']
   }
})
```